# How does Wintertodt damage round?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

Wintertodt damage is calculated based on your HP level, your Firemaking level, the number of warm items you have equipped up to 4, and the number of braziers lit up to 3.

For a standard attack, the formula is:

```
dmg = ((16 - W - 2B) * (HP + 1)) / FM
```

where `W` is the number of warm items up to 4, `B` is the number of braziers lit up to 3, and `HP` and `FM` are your HP and Firemaking levels. Best case scenario, this can be simplified to

```
dmg = (6 * (HP + 1)) / FM
```

How does this damage number round? Does the game use round, floor, or ceiling? For instance, suppose my hitpoints level is 32 and my firemaking level is 79. The calculated damage is 2.5063. Would this round to 3 damage per hit or 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the [Wintertodt's Attacks section](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Wintertodt#Wintertodt's_attacks) of the Wiki, it lists the formulas you mention, and also states the damage is all **rounded down** (floor):

> The following formulas can be used to determine the amount of damage taken, **rounded down**

This information was originally sourced from a [tweet from Mod Ed](https://twitter.com/JagexEd/status/869168964609429504).

Comment: Aha, I should have known I was just missing a small piece from the wiki

Comment: @Unionhawk we 'scapers are quite lucky to have probably the most well documented wiki of any game.

Comment: Also, I don't think it's possible to take less than 1 damage, although the formula when rounded down should allow for it.  I've never seen someone take 0 damage from an attack at Wintertodt.  A 10 HP, 99 Firemaking player with 4 warm items and all braziers lit still takes at least 1 damage from a standard attack, despite the formula resulting in a value of .666 repeating which rounded down is 0.  The game must have an override in place for formulas that result in a value of below 1.

Comment: That is correct, a standard attack will always deal at least 1 damage. I just wanted to know how many HP levels I could gain until I started taking 3s.